# image labels arent imported using csv in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, image, import

I have included info in the image , thumbnail, media, small image labels colummns in my import file but nothing gets updated in magento.

When i do an export only info manually added through the front end is listed in these columns.

How can i import this data?

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of how to import product images with labels in Mage_ImportExport:

```
sku,_media_image,_media_attribute_id,_media_is_disabled,_media_position,_media_lable,image,small_image,thumbnail
1234567,img1.jpg,77,1,1,Image 1,img1.jpg,img2.jpg,img2.jpg
,img2.jpg,77,0,2,Image 2,,,     
,img3.jpg,77,0,3,Image 3,,,
```

The field for the label is `_media_lable` - including the spelling error.

Comment: How can i bulk csv import only image label not image,

Comment: @JeevaRathinam I don't think this is possible, sorry.